# Joomla 3.7.0 Update Saving Articles

Tags: update

Having updated 2 sites to Joomla 3.7.0 I cannot save any articles, the error message is Error decoding JSON data: Syntax error

Template is JSN Epic Pro

Answer (score 2):

This error is probably caused by the improved JSON validation introduced in Joomla 3.6.3.

Sometimes this only affects a few of the modules and can be fixed by running a database query like this or similar (**run a backup first**):

```
update xxxx_modules set params="" WHERE params = "{\"\"}";
```

On some sites, a bit more work is required and the easiest fix is running the script by Rob Went which can be found at: https://github.com/robwent/joomla-json-db-check

It is highly advisable to **run a backup** before running the script but this worked for me on at least one website.

Comment: That Rob Went script fixed a few of my sites in the past.  Highly recommend.